# How can't i refresh ListItemAllFields when site column is updated?

Tags: column

I'm updating site column with this code:

```
Field field = site.Fields.GetById(property.MappedSiteColumn);
clientContext.Load(field);

field.SchemaXml = xml;
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The site column in SharePoint change correctly.

[image]

But, when i search the files that content this site column with this code:

```
File file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(documentUrl);
ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;

clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var fieldValues = item.FieldValues
```

The change in the Site Column is not refreshed in fieldValues variable.
How can't i make this refresh?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the `SchemaXml` of the field, you are setting it in the field that is in the `Fields` collection at the *site level*.

When fields are used in lists and libraries, a *copy* of the field is made and added to the `Fields` collection at the *list level*.  In order for changes to the field at the site level to be pushed down to the field copies at the list level, you have to explicitly tell SharePoint to do that.

In the server side object model, what you would do would be to call [`SPField.Update(true)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms454698(v=office.14)).

Disclaimer - I have very little experience with the CSOM, however, it is my very strong suspicion that what you are going to need to do is call [`Field.UpdateAndPushChanges(true)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544879(v=office.15)).

So your code would look something like

```
Field field = site.Fields.GetById(property.MappedSiteColumn);
clientContext.Load(field);

field.SchemaXml = xml;
field.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, that code help me to refresh the site column in sharepoint file. But in C# code, when exect the code:

File file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(documentUrl);
ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;

clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var fieldValues = item.FieldValues;

The key is the old.

I'd appreciate your help.